# iOS >> UITableViewCell >> Custom Cell >> Row Number

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, row, subclass

Does a UITableViewCell (or a subclass of) has a way to recognise 'on the run' in which Row it is currently at? - not via the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method...

If I subclass UITableViewCell and have some control objects in it (button, text field, etc...), and I wish to respond to that control usage, I wish to respond in consideration to the cell current row; doing so in MYTableViewCell.m file.

What I have done so far, is assign the **tag Property** with the Row number at creation time (cellForRowAtIndexPath); and then I can create my own Protocol in the MYTableViewCell file, create a 'delegate' Property and assign each cell to the VC as its delegate and send it messages. But that seems like a lot to do for something so basic.

Is there a 'built in' way to do that?
Or a simpler way...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know if the row is on-screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

method. I tend to add a tableView property to the cell and set it when creating the cell to the tableView that will own that cell. Then call:

```
[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]
```

Which returns the indexPath for that cell, giving you the section and row. This is better than using a tag of course, since it includes the section, and is always valid, even if the cell changes position (others inserted or deleted above it, or it actually moves).

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the cellatrowforindexpath method to perform such action.
for example if you want to perform some action on button click, you can do like that.

```
cell.buttonName.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and in the action that you have attached to that button do like that.

```
(ibaction)performsomeAction:(id)sender{
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
nslog(@"the row on which i have clicked is %d",btn.tag);
}
```

this will tell you which row you are currently.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to obtain the index path of a cell after touching a control inside it, without using the *tag* property or coupling the cell with its table view.

The first thing to do is to add the target-action to your button, like this:

```
[button addTarget:cell action:@selector(buttonTapped:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then you can use the *event* parameter of the action method:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    // ....
}
```

Or the view hierarchy to retrieve the cell:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // ....
}
```

Or the position of the sender (i.e. the control):

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint position = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:position];        

    // ....
}
```